# Firebase RestApi Filter Not working

Tags: rest, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

While doing restapi call on firebase I want to filter query results so  I am sending a request to

```
https://mydblink.firebaseio.com/user_contacts.json?orderBy="contactNumber"
```

And it returns a response in list of child as (it is all under `user_contacts` table):

> ```
> {
>   "xm6snAk7vbP4kafRA2EmGHwkaDV2_contacts": {
>     "-KjIVzg57e7rREx6zr4Z": {
>       "contactName": "Test",
>       "contactNumber": "123",
>       "contactUsingApp": 0
>     },
>     "-KjIVzg7MoXhCxPIWtJ4": {
>       "contactName": "Free T-Mobile SMS for VVM",
>       "contactNumber": "122",
>       "contactUsingApp": 0
>     },
>     "-KjIVzg8aqzuyS7-90Y7": {
>       "contactName": "Free T-Mobile SMS for VVM",
>       "contactNumber": "129",
>       "contactUsingApp": 0
>     },
>    **"-KjIVzg8aqzuyS7-90Y8": {
>       "contactName": "Test4",
>       "contactNumber": "259",
>       "contactUsingApp": 0
>     }**,
>     "-KjIVzg91jjzOukDq6pc": {
>       "contactName": "Test1",
>       "contactNumber": "321",
>       "contactUsingApp": 0
>     },
>     "-KjIVzg91jjzOukDq6pd": {
>       "contactName": "Test2",
>       "contactNumber": "369",
>       "contactUsingApp": 0
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

And now if I send request filter on another level as:

```
https://mydblink.firebaseio.com/user_contacts.json?orderBy="contactNumber"&equalTo="259"
```

It returns:

> {}

But contact `'259'` is in the database but not returned.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase queries order on values at a known path in child nodes under the location you query.

In the snippet you shared, the only child node is `xm6snAk7vbP4kafRA2EmGHwkaDV2_contacts`. And this child node does not have a property `contactNumber`.

If you query one level deeper, it will work. See

```
https://stackoverflow.firebaseio.com/43782387/xm6snAk7vbP4kafRA2EmGHwkaDV2_contacts.json?orderBy="contactNumber"&equalTo="259"
```

Comment: But docs does not say this, To search in db it is said to index on some key and add query parameters

Comment: I apologize if the docs were not clear. But you can only query properties at a known path under the children of the location where you query.